# Database Error mysqli_init()

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, mysqli

I just changed my server and now I'm getting the following error;

> **Fatal error:** Call to undefined function mysqli_init() in /home/site_address/public_html/system/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_driver.php on line 125

What's the problem and how to solve it?
**Note: changes dbdriver from mysqli to mysql also getting error**

Comment: Is the mysqli PHP extension installed and active? Check your php.ini

Comment: Your new server probably don't have the php_mysqli-extension installed and/or enabled. It's a good thing that the `mysql_*` functions doesn't work, since the mysql-extension have been deprecated since several php-versions back.

Comment: PHP7 doesn't have `mysql_query` and friends and it's never coming back.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your php init file and uncomment the following extension:

`extension=php_mysqli.dll`

Comment: Doubt that will work, since he seem to be on a *nix-server. ;-) (by looking at the path)

Comment: you're right, then must run 

pecl install php-mysql

Comment: ...or if it is something like ubuntu or debian: apt-get install php5-mysql (should contain the mysqli-extension as well)

Comment: where to find php.ini in cPanel ?

Comment: contact hosting support where you have cpanel, 
Some cpanel have php configuration but not all